# How to remain the treeview after redirect to another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

Im currently using this method to bind my treeview,  After i expand the treeview and click the node, it will redirect to another page, and then the treeview will be refresh to default, which means showing the treeview before expanding.. so i need to save the treeview state in order to remain the treeview state. i had tried the below method but it's not working, anyone can help..

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)

           {   

           LoadTransactionMenu();

                     if (Session["ExpandedNodes"] != null)
                    ((List<string>)Session["ExpandedNodes"]).ForEach(a => TreeView1.FindNode(a).Expanded = true);
        }
    }
 private void LoadTransactionMenu()
    {
        //TRANSACTION MENU
        string SubModuleID, SubModuleNM, DocModuleID, DocModuleName, MenuTransID, MenuTransName;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        string CmdString = "SELECT SUBMODULEID, SUBMODULENM, URLNAME FROM SUBMODULE";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode();
        node1.Text = "TRANSACTION MENU";
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node1);
       
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            SubModuleID = dt.Rows[i]["SUBMODULEID"].ToString();
            SubModuleNM = dt.Rows[i]["SUBMODULENM"].ToString();
            TreeNode SubModuleNode = new TreeNode(SubModuleNM, SubModuleID);
            SubModuleNode.NavigateUrl = dt.Rows[i]["URLNAME"].ToString();

            node1.ChildNodes.Add(SubModuleNode);

            CmdString = "SELECT DDID, DOCNAME, DDADDRESS FROM DOCMODULE WHERE SUBMODULEID=@SUBMODULEID";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUBMODULEID", SubModuleID);
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt2);

            for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                DocModuleID = dt2.Rows[j]["DDID"].ToString();
                DocModuleName = dt2.Rows[j]["DOCNAME"].ToString();
                TreeNode DocModuleNode = new TreeNode(DocModuleName, DocModuleID);
                DocModuleNode.NavigateUrl = dt2.Rows[j]["DDADDRESS"].ToString();

                SubModuleNode.ChildNodes.Add(DocModuleNode);

                CmdString = "SELECT DID, DNAME, DADDRESS FROM MENUTRANSACTION WHERE DDID=@DDID AND UID= '" + Session["UserID"] + "'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DDID", DocModuleID);
                sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt3);

                for (int k = 0; k < dt3.Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                    MenuTransID = dt3.Rows[k]["DID"].ToString();
                    MenuTransName = dt3.Rows[k]["DNAME"].ToString();
                    TreeNode MenuTransNode = new TreeNode(MenuTransName, MenuTransID);
                    MenuTransNode.NavigateUrl = dt3.Rows[k]["DADDRESS"].ToString();

                    DocModuleNode.ChildNodes.Add(MenuTransNode);
                }

                if (DocModuleNode.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
                {
                    SubModuleNode.ChildNodes.Remove(DocModuleNode);
                }
            }
            if (SubModuleNode.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
            {
                node1.ChildNodes.Remove(SubModuleNode);
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetExpandedStatus(TreeNode node, List<string> ExpandedNodes)
    {
        //check if node is expanded
        if (node.Expanded.GetValueOrDefault(false))
            ExpandedNodes.Add(node.ValuePath);
        node.ChildNodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList().ForEach(a => GetExpandedStatus(a, ExpandedNodes));
    }

    protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> expandedNodes = new List<string>();
        //get all expanded nodes
        TreeView1.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList().ForEach(a => GetExpandedStatus(a, expandedNodes));
        //collapse all to reset the treeview
        TreeView1.CollapseAll();
        //save expanded node value paths
        Session["ExpandedNodes"] = expandedNodes;
    }
```